SAVING UNIQUE vs SELECT DISTINCT
In a Universe database, when I run the following SQL query:
SELECT DISTINCT INV_LOC_A FROM UNNEST INV ON LOCATIONS;
I get 13729 results. However, when I run the Universe query:
SELECT INV SAVING UNIQUE INV_LOC_A
I get 11697 results.
The INV_LOC_A dictionary is a multivalued field, and part of the LOCATIONS association. Why are these two different values, and which number is correct?

How many records do you get with SELECT DISTINCT INV_LOC_A FROM INV_LOCATIONS

The SQL would be correct. According to UniVerse documentation, the SAVING clause should not be used with multivalued fields.
Out of curiosity, I tried SAVING UNIQUE on one of my multivalued attributes with three values. It returned a count of more than sixty times the correct DISTINCT SQL. Curiously, SAVE.LIST after the SELECT returned a count of a bit more than a quarter of the count on the SELECT.
